# how to make a principal stop/play sound button(div) which does not let other buttons play the sound loops

Tags: jquery, audio, volume

I have **several buttons (divs, called b1 b2 b3 etc.)** which start different animations with different sounds in loop, and the **back home button stops them**. Additionally I created two new **principal buttons (called mute and volume)** in the body for mute/volumed the sound which is playing at that moment. The problem is that when I click again in the other buttons, the music starts again. I would like that the principal mute button keeps silenc even when the animation buttons are click, and music comes back only if the principal volume button is clicked again. Principal buttons which control all other animation buttons on sound. My codes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.id       = 'audio-player';
    audioElement.loop=true;
    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);
    audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.pause();
    }, true);
    
    // in menu

    $('.mute').click(function () {
        audioElement.volume=0.0;
        $('.volume').fadeIn(500, 'easeOutExpo');
        $(this).fadeOut(100, 'easeOutExpo');
    });

    $('.volume').click(function () {
        audioElement.volume=1.0;
        $('.mute').fadeIn(500, 'easeOutExpo');
        $(this).fadeOut(100, 'easeOutExpo');
    });

    $('.b1').click(function(){
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'media/jazzy.mp3');
        audioElement.play();
        fadeInAudio(audioElement, 1000);
    });
    
    $('.b2').click(function(){
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'media/violin.mp3');
        audioElement.play();
        fadeInAudio(audioElement, 1000);
    });
    
    $('.b3').click(function(){
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'media/esoteric.mp3');
        audioElement.play();
        fadeInAudio(audioElement, 1000);
    });

    $('.back-home').click(function(){
        fadeOutAudio(audioElement, 1000);
    });

    function fadeInAudio(audio, fadeTime){ 
        audio.volume = 0; // set volume to the minimum 
        var steps = 500;
        var stepTime = fadeTime/steps;
        var audioIncrement = parseFloat(audio.volume + ("0.00" + steps));

        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            audio.volume += audioIncrement;
            console.clear();
            console.log(audio.volume);

            if (audio.volume >= 0.99){ //if its already audible stop the loop
                console.clear();
                console.log("1");
                audio.volume = 1;
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, stepTime);
    }

    function fadeOutAudio(audio, fadeTime){ 
        audio.volume = 1; // set volume to the maximum 
        var steps = 150;
        var stepTime = fadeTime/steps;
        var audioDecrement = audio.volume / steps;

        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            audio.volume -= audioDecrement;
            console.clear();
            console.log(audio.volume);

            if (audio.volume <= 0.03){ //if its already inaudible stop the loop
                console.clear();
                console.log("0");
                audio.volume = 0;
                audio.pause(); 
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, stepTime);
    }

});
```